# Mapview Points Not Showing in R

Tags: r, r-mapview

When I try to load points in Mapview, the base map will appear centered on the right location but the points do not appear. Below is an image of what it looks like when I attempt to view the pre-loaded Breweries data set. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
library(mapview)

mapview(breweries)
```

CartoDB.positron basemap centered on Würzburg/Nuremberg but no brewery points:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your image is not interactive? In that case you should be able to still see the points (but no changes upon mouse-over) when you run:

```r
library(mapview)
mapviewOptions(fgb = FALSE)
mapview(breweries)
```

Comment: From the help: fgb 
if set to TRUE mapview will not use 'clasical' leaflet/htmlwidgets rendering (which embeds data directly in the html) but leverage the speed of a file format called flatgeobuf (hence, fgb). This has the added benefit that data is being streamed onto the map, which makes for a pleasant user experience. It should also help to visualise larger data sets due to a reduced memeory footprint. A note of warning, data will be attached to the html via a <src=...> call which means that the html is not selfcontained anymore (so it cannot be used without an accompanying folder).

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this and came across this post in my search for a solution.  Same exact symptoms, the base map would appear, centered on the correct location, but no points were rendered.  In my case, I was attempting to take a look at an sf object from a .gdb file.  I discovered that one of the features in this sf object was a list.  After dropping that feature everything worked as expected.